# Extjs listener out of the config

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, listener

Hi extjs experts i have a simple question, but cant find the correct way to do it and was googling in for few days now. I have a listener inside config of extjs elements, it is easy to do it in this way, but how i could take the listener out of the config, and put it outside the config so config will be as minimum as possible and one listener can be used for many times just true the function call,
here is my code:

```
Ext.define("my.filter.TimeFilter",{
extend: "Ext.tab.Panel",
alias: "widget.myTimeFilter",
requires: ["my.filter.Filters"],
config: {
    cls: 'ruban-filter-timefilter',
     items: [
            {
                title: 'Time sections',
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                fieldLabel: 'Time Selector',
                items: [
                    {
                        boxLabel: '60 Mins',
                        name: 'unixMills',
                        inputValue: '3600000'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: '8 Hours',
                        name: 'unixMills',
                        inputValue: '28800000'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: '24 Hours',
                        name: 'unixMills',
                        inputValue: '86400000'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: '7 Days',
                        name: 'unixMills',
                        inputValue: '604800000'
                    }, {
                        boxLabel: '30 Days',
                        name: 'unixMills',
                        inputValue: '2592000000'
                    }
                    ],
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                            var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                            var startTime = endTime - newValue['unixMills'];
                            console.log("StartTime: " + startTime);
                            console.log("EndTime: " + endTime);

                        }


            }
        ]
    },

constructor: function(config){
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

so i believe it should go after constructor as separate function or as listener itself, but i dont know, not so well familiar with js and extjs,
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener outside of the config this way:

```
myElement.on('change', function () { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of possibilities.

If you have a lot of logic based on events, you can always create a controller and have them listen to the components. The controller documentation here should give you a pretty good idea of how to tie it together: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller